# How to Iterate through a list in Google's search bar

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to search items in google's search bar where the items come from an excel spreadsheet. I have no issue importing the items from excel to python but my script never actually enters any of the items into Google's search bar. What is wrong with my loop? I want it to search every item in excel. Thanks.

```
from ast import Return
from operator import index
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd
import time

df = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\Carson\\properties1.csv")
indexx = [df]

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/Carson/Desktop/chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.google.com")

try:
    for element in indexx:
       search =  WebDriverWait(driver, 7).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME,'q')))
       search.click()
       search.send_keys(element)
       search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
       driver.back()
       
except:
    print("Loop Failed")
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: I think you're missing a step when iterating over the DataFrame.  A dataframe has rows and columns.

Comment: This is one of the ways of iterating though a dataframe (if it's not too large) https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html

Comment: seems like you're missing df.iterrows as platipus' link suggests.  There doesn't seem to be a purpose for "indexx = [df]"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue by using the line of code:

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be importing from Excel, because your code worked for me when I run the loop over a list of strings.

Check what comes out of Excel (print the `indexx` list).

Hope I helped,

Jonathan

Comment: Interesting to know it worked for you. My list prints fine when I print the index. I see 400 rows of data all in a single column and each entry seems to be a string.  I made a test list of strings and it worked. Any idea what could go wrong when importing the data from excel?

Comment: Update: when I took the square brackets off of indexx = df, my script then would search the first string but none of the sequential ones.

Comment: You can try with fewer values in the list, check if it works then. If it doesn't work, do tests on each string. you need a list of strings, like: `['str1', 'str2', 'str3']`